# Sylius, search products by slug not working

Tags: symfony, sylius

i'm trying to filter products by slug, using:

```
$this->get('sylius.repository.product')->findOneBy(array('slug' => $slug));
```

I've tried using findBy and findOneBySlug, but it always says that Product does not have a "slug" property:

```
Unrecognized field: slug
```

or

```
Entity 'Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Product' has no field 'slug'. You can therefore not call 'findOneBySlug' on the entities' repository
```

but the documentation on their website says it should be working:
http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/components_and_bundles/bundles/SyliusProductBundle/product.html

```
$product = $repository->findOneBy(array('slug' => 'my-super-product')); // Get one product by defined criteria.
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that doesn't work, because the `slug` is available on the translations of the product. There are some default methods in the repository available that might be helpful to you, e.g.: `findOneByChannelAndSlug` or `findByName`.

Alternatively, you can construct it yourself when extending the product repository:

```
/**
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $locale
 * @return array
 */
public function findBySlug(string $slug, string $locale): ?ProductInterface
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
        ->innerJoin('o.translations', 'translation', 'WITH', 'translation.locale = :locale')
        ->andWhere('translation.slug = :slug')
        ->setParameter('slug', $slug)
        ->setParameter('locale', $locale)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult()
    ;
}
```